# Plotly.js autoscale

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is there a parameter in Plotly.js to autoscale the axes to fit the plotted data automatically?

Scenario: I'm plotting temperature(y-axis) vs. time(x-axis) over the latest 30 minutes.

Problem: When the page loads, the graph shows nothing. I would fix the axes, but the x-axis needs to show latest 30 minutes and update every minute. However, when I click 'Autoscale' or 'Reset Axes', the graph fits the data perfectly!

Question: Can I set the plot to automatically "Autoscale" when the page loads, rather than requiring a user to click 'autoscale'?

See app here: https://vast-fortress-23871.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A really silly hack is to add this:

```
document.querySelector('[data-title="Autoscale"]').click()
```

It will automatically click the Autoscale button. A better way would be to figure out what function the button is actually calling and call that instead.

Comment: That's clever, thanks. If all else fails, I'll use this.

Comment: @Matte3o: Since you're using JQuery, you can of course use `$` instead of `document.querySelector`, for wider browser support.

Answer (score 5):

For me, this worked perfectly and simply (thanks to https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/KpLVzv):

```
// script comes before
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    autorange: true,
    showgrid: false,
    zeroline: false,
    showline: false,
    etc.
    }
// script comes after
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what the user wants, as they talk of on initial display being the problem, but probably safest to include the yaxis too.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem with a relayout. Just set autorange property at 'true' on xaxis and yaxis. It will autoscale on both axis :

```
// To call when data is ready, after your page loads.
Plotly.relayout( yourGraph, {
    'xaxis.autorange': true,
    'yaxis.autorange': true
});
```

Comment: I like this as it's using relayout which sounds like the functions correct purpose, and is the first result I hit from the official forums https://community.plotly.com/t/solved-how-to-progamatically-autoscale-plot/3278

Comment: Its working in my case but it doesn't autoscale one of the subplots that I have in my plot!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The code you linked to is minified so I can't (won't) read it, but here's what I did wrong:

If  `plotly.newPlot()` runs before all the data is loaded then it won't autorange (because it has no data and doesn't know to check).

eg

```
var plotdata = [x:[],y:[],type: 'scatter'];
$.get('mydata.dat',(x) => {/*put parsed x into plotdata*/});
Plotly.newPlot('mydiv',plotdata,layout);
```

note that plotdata gets populated after the plot was created because `$.get()` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked perfectly and simply:
    .
    .
    var layout = {
      xaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        showgrid: false,
        zeroline: false,
        showline: false,
        etc.
        }